# Failing to import numpy

Tags: numpy, pip, pycharm, command-prompt

I am very new to Python, I need to use the module numpy. I have deleted and re-installed both Python and PyCharm several times so that might have created problems. When I open the command prompt and I run `py --version` I have no problems and also when I run `py -m pip --version` I get the right answer from the system, I also downloaded numpy already, but when I try to import it I get the message import is not recognized. Below I included the command prompt commands and errors.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2965]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\feder>py -m pip --version
pip 23.1.2 from C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.11)

C:\Users\feder>C:\Program Files\Python311
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\feder>import numpy
'import' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\feder>
```

Online I found that the mistake is that I am running a windows shell prompt but I have no idea how not to.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using PyCharm IDE (I assume you installed it correctly), you don't need to use the Windows command prompt to install NumPy. You can directly install all the required packages for your project with the PyCharm python interpreter.

To do so, first create a new project in PyCharm and define the environment by selecting "Virtualenv" (select from the drop-down menu of New environment). Then select the available python version as the base interpreter and in the drop-down menu, you should be able to see the python version that you installed. Once you create the project, you should be able to access the terminal where you'll find the name of the environment (by default the name would be 'pythonProject') you just created. Type in the following command in the terminal to install numpy via pip (the most convenient way):

```
pip install numpy
```

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zCO3KxV2zPI) is a video tutorial where you can find other ways to install python packages (including NumPy) in PyCharm.